# How to change color of textInputlayout when it's clicked

Tags: android

I have a textInputLayout which uses my theme's `colorPrimaryDark` but when tapped, the line and hint text changes to my theme's `colorPrimary` which I'd like to change.

[image: This is before the textInputLayout is tapped]\

[image: And this is after its tapped]

XML Code

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Style code

```
<style name="StyledEditText">

    <item name="android:imeOptions">actionNone</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

Comment: You have not implemented the style code!

Comment: Sorry, I implemented it but it still did not work but later removed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First way**

**Its sync with your `colorAccent` in colors**

You can change your `colorAccent` to any color you want.

**Second way :**

You can customize colorAccent` in your style then use it in your textInputLayout like this :

```
  <style name="StyledEditText">

        <item name="android:imeOptions">actionNone</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">#FFFFFF</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it still doesn't work for me. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Sorry it did work, it was my mistake. I implemented the style as `style="@style/StyledEditText"` instead of `android:theme="@style/StyledEditText"`. Thanks again.

Comment: Your welcome , you can handle it from colors in resource folder too, if its useful please accept my answer :P

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/TextLabel"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Add Following style **TextLabel** in your code:

```
 <style name="TextLabel" parent="Widget.Design.TextInputLayout">
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@android:color/holo_red_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ff000000</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/holo_green_dark</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/holo_purple</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@android:color/holo_blue_bright</item>
</style>
```

the `colorControlActivated` sets the color of the edit text field when it is focused. `colorControlNormal` is the default color when the field is not focused.